# Conversión de datos a tipo Enum Sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite

Trabajo con C#, Sqlite, Visual Studio 2015 tengo un tipo de dato que `enum`

```
 public enum AmbienteType : int
 {
    [Description("PRUEBA")]
    Prueba = 1,
    [Description("PRODUCCIÓN")]
    Produccion = 2
 }
```

Al momento de hacer la búsqueda que me trae un solo registro no reconoce cuando `casteo`.

```
entity.Ambiente = (AmbienteType) (reader["Ambiente"]);
```

En la base de datos `Ambiente` es de tipo `Int`

**¿Como puedo solucionarlo?**
De antemano gracias.

Comment: intenta con `entity.Ambiente = (AmbienteType) ((int)reader["Ambiente"]);`

Comment: @Pikoh me da el mismo error: La conversión especificada no es válida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si usas para acceder a la columna de un `reader` la indexación tipo array (`[""]`)  por defecto devuelve un objeto de tipo `object`. Para castear a un enum, necesitas un `int`. Asi que lo que debes hacer es castear el reader a `long`, y despues a `AmbienteType`:

```
entity.Ambiente = (AmbienteType) ((long)reader["Ambiente"]);
```

Comment: Me sale este error: La conversión especificada no es válida.

Comment: @PedroÁvila estas seguro de que `reader["Ambiente"]` es de tipo int? Comprueba primero eso

Comment: Revisando dice bigint

Comment: @PedroÁvila bigint no existe en c#...existe BigInteger. A no ser que te refieras a el tipo en la base de datos...Si es asi, el equivalente es long.

Comment: Efectivamente, actualiza tu respuesta para marcarla.

Comment: Que raro cuando cree la tabla tanto al key incrementado como a Ambiente le puse INT pero cuando ya crea la tabla aparece con bigint, a que se deberá que SqLite ofrece un tipo de dato INT pero cuando ya crea la tabla el campo aparece con bigint.